# Graph theory with friends

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ people, and each person has maximum $k$ friends. (If A is friend with B, then B is friend with A) Does anyone know how to minimize the number of groups($m$) of people which satisfies the condition : The groups should partition the people into $m$ groups which satisfies the condition : For every person, there are maximum three friends in the same group.
I thought of Turan Theorem but I recognized that it's not that related.

Comment: Why you have friends in the question but enemies in the title?

Comment: If you change "three" to "zero" you have the hard problem: "A graph has maximum degree $k$, how do you finf the chromatic number." Do you really think your problem will be any easier?

Comment: What about the $n$ and $k$ is given as constant? e.g. $n=100$, $k=10$.